# BootupReceiver in Android 3.1

Tags: android

I want to know if there are any changes in boot up event in Android 3.1+, I do not recieve it in 3.1 whereas on android 2.2 it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of applications that are in a stopped state and provides a means of controlling their launch from background processes and other applications.
More details here
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols